# How can I make a class not extendable without using the final keyword?

Tags: java, class

How can I achieve this without the `final` keyword? What must I change to the constructors?

```
 public final class testName {
     testName() {
        //do something
     }
 }
```

Comment: why without using final?

Comment: what is your motivation ? The final keyword is supposed to meet your above requirement.Do you want to become an syntax expert of java?

Comment: yes it is a test that i have to solve

Comment: well if it is a test why don't you try running things against javac?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you make all your Constructors `private`, then the class will also no longer be extendable.

```
public class TestName {

    private TestName(){do something}

}
```

To see why, check section 3.4.4.1, ['The default constructor'](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_04.htm). By declaring your private default constructor, the last sentence of the paragraph holds:

> Such a [private] constructor can never be invoked from outside of the class, but it prevents the automatic insertion of the default constructor.

So effectively by declaring a constructor in the superclass that is not accessible, there is no (other) constructor that your subclass could call and thus Java prevents compilation.

Comment: If you still need an alternative to the public constructor, you can add a static method that returns a new object using the private constructor:

Comment: @emboss could u explain why making the constructors private makes it not extendable

Comment: Each constructor in a subclass must invoke a super constructor. If not, the implicit constructor is used. Making all super constructors private (including the implicit one) will lead to compilation error.

Comment: Because a class must have at least one constructor (the compiler generates one for you if you don't supply one), and a subclass constructor is forced to call one of its superclass constructor as its first statement (The compiler inserts a call to the default super constructorif you don't do it explicitely). If all the superclass constructors are private, it's impossible to compile a subclass.

Comment: ty all of you guys and something else if i have and methods i have to make them private too?

Comment: and if i try to make an object from this class could i create it?

Answer (score 3):

If the constructor should fail due to code inserted at the "//do something" comment, then throw an exception.

The other options -- final class or private constructor -- are better choices, generally, because they report the error at compile time, rather than run time.  But if the failure should be conditional, or if someone is testing your knowledge, then throwing an exception is the usual approach.

[Expert question:  If the constructor throws an exception, is there any way the program can still end up with a reference to the newly created instance?  (Hint: Yes.) ]

Comment: I would give you +10 for the awesome expert question if I could. Thanks, Jeff.

Answer (score 0):

You can make private constructor of that class.